# How to fix horizontal lines on YouTube video on Google Chrome (No issue on Firefox)

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, youtube

So i'm facing this strange issue when watching YouTube videos on **Google Chrome**. There appear some horizontal lines when you hover the cursor on video as shown in screenshot. I have checked on Firefox but there is no such issue there. Any way to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Try tinkering with hardware acceleration in settings or start with a brand new profile with default settings/no addons or extensions and see if it happens there.

Comment: @kortewegdevries So i have disable _**Use hardware acceleration when available**_ and it seems to be fixed. Can you give some thoughts about this option. Is it okay to keep this option disable? On Windows  i had kept this option enable by default.

Comment: Probably some gpu incompatibility on linux. If you want to use HA, it's already in firefox 80 for Xorg (the option is meant to use gpu processing power to increase playback quality etc.)

Comment: It's integrated graphics _Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)_ By the way i also think that this laptop is not much compatible with Linux. Thank you very much for your help though.

Comment: It's old try some of these if it helps https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntelQuickSyncVideo I haven't used Intel's integrated graphics, sorry.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using 20.04,
Disabling the 'Use hardware acceleration when available' option works for me.
Open a new tab and type the following
chrome://settings/?search=hardware

Turn-off the option `Use hardware acceleration when available` and relaunch the browser.
Hope this helps

Comment: worked perfectly

Comment: Works for other chrome-based browsers too.

Answer (score 4):

Set page zoom to 90% and those lines will dissapear, but this only work when you watch video in normal and full screen mode. Hope it will be helpul  :D

Answer (score 1):

For intel integrated graphics drive do this command:

```
sudo apt install '*video-intel*'
```

Quotes are needed so that `apt` will handle the wildcard (as opposed to the shell globbing it). It may work if they're isn't any matching filenames, but quotes are better just in case there *are* matching filenames. Credit to Jeff Schaller for part of the explanation about quotes.

asterick * is used to tell terminal to select specifically 'video-intel- packs and install them. Look for 'hwe' in the name of the packs. That is the driver to support hardware acceleration. Those lines are caused due lack of hardware acceleration driver. I installed 'hwe' driver and it worked. Everything is now buttery smooth and youtube player lines are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Disable 'Use hardware acceleration when available' also worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Enable vulkan in `chrome://flags` and it was fixed

Comment: In Kubuntu 23.04 enabling vulkan brakes youtube playback completely.